# Using rememberSaveable with mutableStateListOf

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add a mutable list of parcelable objects to my composable. I also want to be able to add objects to and remove objects from it.

Currently I'm using something like this:

```kotlin
val names = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }

names.add("Bill")
names.remove("Bill")
```

Now I want this list to survive configuration change, therefore it's perhaps a good idea to use `rememberSaveable`. Perhaps something like this:

```kotlin
val names = rememberSaveable { mutableStateListOf<String>() }

names.add("Bill")
names.remove("Bill")
```

But this does not work, it throws the following exception:

> androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList cannot be saved
> using the current SaveableStateRegistry. The default implementation
> only supports types which can be stored inside the Bundle. Please
> consider implementing a custom Saver for this class and pass it to
> rememberSaveable().

This means, that `SnapshotStateList` (the result of `mutableStateListOf`) is not saveable.

So far I can think of few ways how to work around this:

1. Actually implementing a saver for `SnapshotStateList`.
2. Using something like `val namesState = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(listOf<String>()) }`.
   This does indeed work flawlessly, however updating the list requires setting the value, which is both slow and inconvenient (e.g. `namesState.value = namesState.value + "Joe"` for just adding a single element).

Both these ways seem too complicated for a seemingly small task. I wonder what is the best way to do what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There should be no data inside `remember` or `rememberSaveable` that you are afraid of losing: it's gonna be destroyed as soon as your `Composable` disappears (goes out of composition, to be precise). Consider using [view models](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state) in this case.

---

If you are still interested in storing `mutableStateListOf` inside `rememberSaveable`, I suggest that you follow your error recommendation and create a `Saver` for `SnapshotStateList`:

```
@Composable
fun <T: Any> rememberMutableStateListOf(vararg elements: T): SnapshotStateList<T> {
    return rememberSaveable(
        saver = listSaver(
            save = { stateList ->
                if (stateList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val first = stateList.first()
                    if (!canBeSaved(first)) {
                        throw IllegalStateException("${first::class} cannot be saved. By default only types which can be stored in the Bundle class can be saved.")
                    }
                }
                stateList.toList()
            },
            restore = { it.toMutableStateList() }
        )
    ) {
        elements.toList().toMutableStateList()
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
val names = rememberMutableStateListOf<String>()
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    names.add("Bill")
}
Text(names.joinToString { it })
```

The expected behaviour for this sample: each time you rotate your device - one more element gets added.

Don't use any state modifications inside the composable like you did when you added and removed an item. You should only do that inside [side-effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects), like I did here with `LaunchedEffect`, or callbacks, like `onClick`.

Note that `saveableMutableStateListOf` is still limited to Bundle-saveable types, like `String`, `Int`, etc. If you need to store a custom type inside, you will need to modify `Saver` to save/recreate it too.

Comment: Thanks Philip, this works and does solve my problem. Perhaps this is the most elegant we can do at this point... I also added `Parcelable` class to `T`, so that items could always be saved.

Is this really the way it's intended to be done? I think having a saveable mutable array is not something far-fetched and should be easily available out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with view models, and they fit really well here.

Comment: You are brilliant, phil

Comment: How can I use like `by rememberMutableStateListOf<Int>()`? I think I need to implement getValue. But I have no idea.

Comment: @c-an no, you can't do it. `SnapshotStateList` is not subclass of `State`, instead it implements `MutableList` interface, so you can modify it same as you'd do with any other mutable list, and you don't need `by` delegation here

Comment: Making objects parcelable will make it possible to `'Bundle-save'` them https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something like this

```
val selectedLists: MutableList<String?> = rememberSaveable(
    saver = listSaver<MutableList<String?>, String?>(
        save = {
            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                it.toList()
            } else {
                listOf<String?>(null)
            }
        },
        restore = {
            it.toMutableStateList()
        }
    )
) {
    mutableStateListOf(*viewState.selectedLists.map { it.name }.toTypedArray())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The kind of data you are storing must be saveable in a Bundle, or else, you must pass in a custom-saver object. Just look at the docs for state and maybe specifically for `rememberSaveable`

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
var snackbars by rememberSaveable(
    stateSaver = listSaver(
        save = {
            buildList {
                add(it.size)
                it.forEach {
                    add(it.id)
                    add(it.message)
                    add(it.actionLabel)
                    add(it.withDismissAction)
                    add(it.duration)
                    add(it.delay)
                }
            }
        },
        restore = { list: List<*> ->
            val size = list[0] as Int
            val snackbarSize = 6
            buildList {
                repeat(size) {
                    val i = it * snackbarSize
                    add(
                        Snackbar(
                            id = list[i + 1] as Long,
                            message = list[i + 2] as String,
                            actionLabel = list[i + 3] as String?,
                            withDismissAction = list[i + 4] as Boolean,
                            duration = list[i + 5] as SnackbarDuration,
                            delay = list[i + 6] as Long,
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ),
) { mutableStateOf(listOf()) }
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the following solution for myself:

1. I create a saver function in which I convert a list of strings into a string separated by '\n' and vice versa:

   ```
    fun saverListOfString(): Saver <MutableList<String>, String> = Saver(
    save = {
        var saved = ""
        it.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
            if (index > 0) saved += "\n"
            saved += s
        }
        saved
    },
    restore = { restored ->
        val restoredList = restored.lines()
        val list = mutableStateListOf<String>()
        restoredList.forEach { list.add(it) }
        list
    }
   ```

   )
2. I save the list of strings in Saveable like this:

```kotlin
val stringList = rememberSaveable(saver = saverListOfString()) { mutableStateListOf() }
```

Comment: This is very un-kotlin code (is that a word?) and doesn't make much sense. There are easier ways to serialize a list, and using \n as a seperator makes no sense if the strings themselves contain that

Comment: Either use a ViewModel (your UI layer should only display UI, it shouldn't be responsible for saving state) or implement the saver as such: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887484/3999808