# correct way to handle mutable state of list of data in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

For a mutable state containing integer like this,

```
var data by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(-1)
}
```

We can update data using

```
data = 5
```

And it would update the data and trigger recomposition.

Now, my requirement is to remember a **list of integers**.

Declared like this,

```
var data by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(mutableListOf<Int>())
}
```

The list operations like `clear()`, `add()`, and `remove()` update the data in the list but recomposition is not triggered as the list instance is still the same.

To handle this, I replaced the following list operations with these assignments.

1. Instead of `data.clear()`, used `data = arrayListOf()`
2. Instead of `data.add(ele)`, used `data = mutableListOf(*data.toTypedArray(), ele)`

Similarly, for `remove()` tried this,

```
data.remove(ele)
data = mutableListOf(*data.toTypedArray())
```

But this is not triggering recomposition.

What is the correct alternative for `remove()`?
And is there any generic to handle all list operations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Declare your list as `mutableStateListOf`. In this case you can do any operations on it, like `clear()`, `add()`, `remove()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887484/3585796) how you can use it with `rememberSaveable`, or move it to the view model.

   ```
   val data = remember {
       mutableStateListOf<Int>()
   }
   data.clear()
   ```
2. Sometimes it's more comfortable to use `mutableStateOf`, in this case you can update it value like this:

   ```
   var data by rememberSaveable(Unit) {
       mutableStateOf(listOf<Int>())
   }
   data = data.toMutableList().apply {
       clear()
   }.toImmutableList()
   ```

Comment: Getting this error, `Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate`. I have these 2 imports - `import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue` and `import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue`. Not sure, what I am missing.

Comment: Yup, missed that. Was trying with delegation. Now I ended up in [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68885154/using-remembersaveable-with-mutablestatelistof). For a simple list of integers, I have to manually create a custom saver?

Comment: @Abhimanyu Looks like you've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887484/3585796). I've added a link to it to this answer too