# UI in Jetpack Compose recomposes when the stateArrayList is null but don't when it is empty

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a state

```
val selectedRationList: MutableStateFlow<ArrayList<Ration>?> = MutableStateFlow(null)`
```

I updated this like this

```
uiState.selectedRationList.update { data }
```

The problem here is that when the list becomes empty, it recomposes the UI only once and doesn't recompose whether you try to add new items to the list or remove them.

But when it became empty I did it like this

```
if (data.isEmpty()) {
    state.selectedRationList.value = null
} else {
    state.selectedRationList.value = data
}
```

It recomposes as many times I add new items or remove them. Why?

Comment: You have to use `mutableStateListOf()` as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69932964/9636037)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [correct way to handle mutable state of list of data in jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932411/correct-way-to-handle-mutable-state-of-list-of-data-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 0):

`MutableStateFlow` only recomposes when the value changes, but list operation does not change the value.

Use `mutableStateListOf<Ration>()`.

For example:

```
val selectedRationList = mutableStateListOf<Ration>()

selectedRationList.add(Ration())
selectedRationList.removeLast()
```