# How to create a dynamic views in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I am trying to create a some dynamic views when the user clicks add button it starts a new set of text fields and fill the required details and add all the set to final list of array i facing a problem of how to deal with the mutable state of each text field i.e value and onValueChange the text fields are sharing same viewModel mutable state.

[image: the one]

How to deal with the dynamic views so that only the required text field value changes instead of all similar text field changing

Ui code

```
@Composable
fun CombineFields(viewModel: MainContentUploadViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {


val containerTitle = viewModel.containerTitle.value
val containerAbout = viewModel.containerAbout.value



OutlinedTextField(value = containerTitle.innerStateTitle,
    onValueChange = { viewModel.onEvent(MainContentEvent.ContainerTitle(it)) },
    label = { Text(text = "Title") })

Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

TextField(value = containerAbout.innerStateAbout,
    onValueChange = { viewModel.onEvent(MainContentEvent.ContainerAbout(it)) },
    modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))

Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

val options = listOf("Products", "Banners", "Categories")
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }
// We want to react on tap/press on TextField to show menu
ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = {
        expanded = !expanded
    }
) {
    TextField(
        readOnly = true,
        value = selectedOptionText,
        onValueChange = { },
        label = { Text("Label") },
        trailingIcon = {
            ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                expanded = expanded
            )
        },
        colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors()
    )
    ExposedDropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = {
            expanded = false
        }
    ) {
        options.forEach { selectionOption ->
            DropdownMenuItem(
                onClick = {
                    selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                    expanded = false
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = selectionOption)
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

ViewModel

```
 @HiltViewModel
   class MainContentUploadViewModel @Inject constructor(private val useCases: UseCases)    : ViewModel() {

private val _containerTitle = mutableStateOf(MainContentFieldState())
    val containerTitle : State<MainContentFieldState> = _containerTitle

private val _containerAbout = mutableStateOf(MainContentFieldState())
    val containerAbout : State<MainContentFieldState> = _containerAbout

private val _containerPriority = mutableStateOf(MainContentFieldState())
val containerPriority : State<MainContentFieldState> = _containerPriority

private val _selectedContent = mutableStateOf(MainContentFieldState())
    val selectedContent : State<MainContentFieldState> = _selectedContent

private val _selectedTags = mutableStateOf(MainContentFieldState())
    val selectedTags : State<MainContentFieldState> = _selectedTags

private val _allInnerContent = mutableStateOf(MainContentFieldState())
    val allInnerContent : State<MainContentFieldState> = _allInnerContent
```

Data Class

```
data class InnerContainerItems(
val containerName:String? = null,
val containerAbout:String? = null,
val containerTags:List<String>? = null,
val containerType:String? = null,
val containerPriority:Int? = null,

)

data class MainScreenContainer(
  val ScreenContainer:List<InnerContainerItems>? = null
)
```

can anyone help me how to move further for the dynamic fields thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using `var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }`
I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887484/20839582. Check if it is useful as it mentions using mutableStateListOf and rememberSaveable.