Using rememberSave with mutableListOf in Jetpack Compose
data class Score(
    val name: String,
    var play: Int,
    var out: Int,
    var total: Int,
    var prev: Int
  )

 var players = remember {mutableListOf<Score>(
      Score("Player A", 0, 0, 0, 0),
      Score("Player B", 0, 0, 0, 0),
      Score("Player C", 0, 0, 0, 0)
    )
  }

This code fragment defines and initializes a data class in Jetpack Compose.
How can I extend the code with a custom saver and restore using remeberSaved and ListSaver so that the state persists after configuration changes ?
I have tried various recommendations without success.

Since storing a MutableList in remember doesn't make sense I guess you meant mutableStateListOf instead of mutableListOf. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68885154/using-remembersaveable-with-mutablestatelistof for how that is done with rememberSaveable().

A more effective way to build the solution is to use a ViewModel in the file MainViewModel.kt
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

data class Score(
    var name: String,
    var play: Int,
    var out: Int,
    var total: Int
)

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val players: SnapshotStateList<Score> = mutableStateListOf(
      Score("Player 1", 0, 0, 0),
      Score("Player 2", 0, 0, 0),
      Score("Player 3", 0, 0, 0)
    )
}

In the MainActivity.kt, the data class can then be accessed using the following

import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

@Composable
fun ScoreSummary(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  playersViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
) {

  val players = playersViewModel.players

}


Data in the list can then be read and updated using the following code


for ((index, score) in players.withIndex()) {

  Text(text = score.name, fontSize = 24.sp, color = Color.Cyan)

  players[index] = players[index].copy(play = players[index].play + 1)

}


Additional dependencies must be added to the project build.gradle.kts

  implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
  implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
  implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)


Data in the ViewModel is then persisted when there are configuration changes. Therefore I found my own solution but not in the way I originally planned. ViewModel seems to be much simpler and more reliable.
